# Possible to make mbsync (isync) update multiple multiple IMAP folders at once?

Tags: email, imap

When running `mbsync -a`, it goes over each folder, updating it.

This gets slow if you have many folders (20+ for e.g.).

Is there a way to update multiple folders at once?